# IComparer in c# from msdn sample -- Misleading on MSDN part

Tags: c#, .net

I have following method:

```
public static void OrderByDescendingEx1()
{
    List<decimal> decimals = new List<decimal> { 6.2m, 8.3m, 0.5m, 1.3m, 6.3m, 9.7m };

    IEnumerable<decimal> query =  
        decimals.OrderByDescending(num => num, new SpecialComparer());

    foreach (decimal num in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of `IComparer`

```
public class SpecialComparer : IComparer<decimal>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two decimal numbers by their fractional parts.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d1">The first decimal to compare.</param>
    /// <param name="d2">The second decimal to compare.</param>
    /// <returns>1 if the first decimal's fractional part 
    /// is greater than the second decimal's fractional part,
    /// -1 if the first decimal's fractional
    /// part is less than the second decimal's fractional part,
    /// or the result of calling Decimal.Compare()
    /// if the fractional parts are equal.</returns>
    public int Compare(decimal d1, decimal d2)
    {
        decimal fractional1, fractional2;

        // Get the fractional part of the first number.
        try
        {
            fractional1 = decimal.Remainder(d1, decimal.Floor(d1));
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            fractional1 = d1;
        }

        // Get the fractional part of the second number.
        try
        {
            fractional2 = decimal.Remainder(d2, decimal.Floor(d2));
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            fractional2 = d2;
        }

        if (fractional1 == fractional2)
            return Decimal.Compare(d1, d2);
        else if (fractional1 > fractional2)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
 /*
         This code produces the following output:

         9.7
         0.5
         8.3
         6.3
         1.3
         6.2
        */
```

So my question is both mathematical and c# related. The output is not sorted descendingly. Then why this code is correct?

**Update**

in explanation Microsoft wrote :" to sort the elements of a sequence in descending order ". Better, a lot better, would be if they have said `to sort the elements' fractions of a sequence in descending order`.

Its not complicated English that they used, its simple:`to sort the elements of a sequence in descending order` does not means sorting fractions of elements of a sequence

Comment: Post the link to the msdn article.

Comment: I do not understand your question. The output **is** in descending order (but it first orders by decimals, and only uses the whole part only in case of a tie, as your comparer logic shows)

Comment: The output is correct according to the written code so what's the question? The code sorts the list descending by the fraction parts then if the fraction parts are equal by the decimal parts.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code is correct not because it orders the collection in descending order, but because it is intended to show what it means to create customized Comparer.

In this case, microsoft is being "playful" by showing that, on one hand you implement comparing by fractional and ordering it by fractional correctly:

```
//Let's call this View 1

.7
.5
.3
.3
.3
.2
```

But on the other hand also *not* descending it by real value correctly except for the tie break situation:

```
//Let's call this View 2

9.7
0.5
8.3
6.3
1.3
6.2
```

To me, it serves *double* purpose to say that:

1. It is a *correct descending* Comparer (by showing that it orders based on fractional *correctly*) - View 1
2. It is a *customized* Comparer (by showing that it orders based on *fractional* part) - View 2

And I personally think that it is a *thoughtful* (smart) example. Had Microsoft not create customized Comparer like that, the example might be more ambiguous, since people may miss any of the two points above. I.e:

1. It is a correct comparer but does not seem to be customized:

   ```
    5.6, 4.5, 3.7, 2.9
   ```
2. It is not a comparer (if the data result shows no pattern):

   ```
   +, ?, &, 54, u
   ```

Comment: In short, why would you use a custom comparer when you want to compare using the *default* rules? That's what the default comparer is for! :)

Comment: Yes! That's it! :)

Answer (score 5):

The data *is* in descending order - as defined by the comparer.

The comparer orders by fractional part of the decimal, and uses the rest only for tie-breakers. So `1.2` comes before `1.3` *and* `0.3`, but after `12.1`. That's why you even had to write your own comparer - you wanted something *else* than the usual comparison.

Comment: so u are saying the code on msdn, which says:` to sort the elements of a sequence in descending order by using a transform function and a custom comparer.` is right. but i think its little misleading. dont u think?

Comment: @Alex All you've posted contains `1 if the first decimal's fractional part is greater than the second decimal's fractional part, -1 if the first decimal's fractional part is less than the second decimal's fractional part, or the result of calling Decimal.Compare() if the fractional parts are equal.`, which is quite unambiguous. But yes, even the title you mentioned now is perfectly fine - the transform function and a custom comparer enable you to define what descending order *is*. Just don't assume that there's one way to order a given set of data.

Comment: why its so hard to call the info on msdn is bit misleading. its clearly said what i wrote in my comment?just a few lines of explanation might suffice but they didnt bother to add. i think code says one thing but explanation is completely misleading. yes or no?

Comment: @Alex No, it isn't misleading at all. `Sorts the elements of a sequence in descending order by using a specified comparer.` That's what `OrderByDescending` does, and nothing else. What is so "misleading" about that? The sample shows you how to implement your own comparer for use with the `OrderByDescending` method, and again, `in descending order by using a transform function and a custom comparer`. I'm the last guy to say that MSDN samples are of high quality, but this is definitely not the problem here. Are you just trying to pick on MSDN for no reason?

Comment: look at this again:`to sort the elements of a sequence in descending order` what does it sound like?. they should have said "fractions in descending order"

Comment: @Alex No, they shouldn't, and it would be wrong anyway. "In **a** descending order" might be better, but that's not commonly used in US English. There's no definite objective order to things, and if you assume there is, you're going to get hurt badly. Try sorting this in descending order: A, b, #, 42.

Comment: no sir, its simple English. they think everyone can make sense out of their samples, what is the reason of 10s of lines of explanation if its wrong?

Comment: @Alex Tens of lines of explanation *where* exactly? You interpreted the text wrong, which happens all the time, just learn from it and move on. StackOverflow is not a forum for ranting, it's a Q&A site. If you came here to rant, better close the question and go somewhere else. If you think the sample could be improved, tell the MSDN guys. But make sure that your "improvement" actually makes the sample better - the examples you posted so far are harder to understand, and outright wrong. And stop assuming that there's one correct way to do or understand something - it only sounds right to you.